# Error ld returned 1 exit status en C++

Tags: c++

Me marca un error en mi codigo pero ya verifique todo y parece estar bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

LINK DEL CODIGO
https://pastebin.com/NH6jgcjr

Comment: El código relevante **debería** ser parte de la pregunta. ¿ Te has pasado por [Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Y las imágenes no es que ayuden mucho, no se pueden copiar ni probar.

Comment: Para poder probarlo deberíamos tener el código completo que hace referencia a LIbros y Recargos